# SQL Query to compare (HL7) value at certain position in string based on delimiters (not position)

Tags: substring

This is complicated by the fact that I don't know what DBMS the backend uses.  I know it's Cache, but I don't seem to be able to do anything but the most basic commands.  I cannot seem to SET or DECLARE variables.

Here is an example:

> MSH|^~\&|unimportant|This is the substring I want^123123123^ABC|unimportant|...

So let's call that specific substring SendingFacility.  **What is the simplest, most compatible way, to write something like this:**

```
SELECT * WHERE SendingFacility = 'This is the substring I want'
```

I tried `SELECT WHERE SendingFacility REGEXP '<some regex>'` but I get the following error:

`[Error Code: 14, SQL State: 37000]  [SQLCODE: <-14>:<A comparison operator is required here>]`

If this looks like HL7 that's because it is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
SELECT *
FROM    
       TABLE
WHERE   
       $PIECE($PIECE(HL7Message,'|',4),'^',1) = 'This is the substring I want'
```

or to get Sendingfacilities based on other criteria

```
SELECT $PIECE($PIECE(HL7Message,'|',4),'^',1) as SendingFacility
FROM TABLE
WHERE <whatever>
```